# Swipe to Delete a Cell in a Table using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I had previously a working implementation where I had a single TableViewController, I press the ADD button, it brings up another view controller which lets the user add text to fields - that in turn adds that information over to the entities and attributes and I could display that in the Table View. Implementing the following methods, I could swipe to delete a row successfully:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.transactions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I've managed to successfully implement the NSFetchedResultsController to allow the same functionality with the adding and fetching of information, but just more secure. What I cannot figure out now is how to actually implement the same swipe to delete functionality.

I added the:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

I added this and the "swipe" gesture just doesn't work to delete cells.

In the NSFetchedReusltsController code for the datasource, I have:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

along with all of the required methods, but the swipe to delete action is just not working.

Any thoughts with this would be massively helpful.

Comment: Create an empty project that use core data and look at the implementation of FRC and table view delegate methods, it should be very similar to what you need.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I did that and with the answer below, I got it working. Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To delete a row from the table, you just have to delete the corresponding
Core Data object:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

That's all, in particular you need not call `reloadData`.
Deleting the object triggers the
fetched results controller delegate methods, and that updates the table view.

Now from your code it seems that you have a data source array `self.transactions`.
That is wrong and you should remove it. All data source methods must get the information
from the fetched results controller directly.

Comment: Hi Martin - That's just brilliant. That works like a treat and thanks so much for that. Indeed, the self-transactions was before i implemented the NSFetchedResultsController and that worked brilliantly. I guess I was thinking that perhaps the switch statement inside the didChangeObject: forChangeType: newIndexPath: was where this code had to go, etc. You're the man and I really appreciate it!